# How to delete duplicates rows in openrefine by comparing one column value?

Tags: openrefine

I have 20000 duplicate rows in a csv and i'm trying to remove the duplicates using openrefine. My problem is, I want to delete the duplicate who's quantity is less. In the image, If you look at first two rows, row 136 has quantity as 1 and row 137 has quantity as 3 otherwise all parameters are same, so, i want to keep the row 137 and delete row 136.
How can I achieve this using OpenRefine?
[OpenRefine Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk0ip.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpenRefine you can sort by multiple columns at the same time. In your case:

- first sort by `invoice number`
- then sort by `Quantity` and select sort by `number`, `largest first`, and leave the option `sort by this column alone` untick.

By doing so it will sort by invoice number and Quantity. Then you can follow the [process to remove duplicate using OpenRefine](http://kb.refinepro.com/2011/08/remove-duplicate.html) here.

[image]